# Avis Rent-a-Car's slogan 'We're #2' : This is an Appeal to Pity?

Tags: fallacies

<sub>Source: p 238, *With Good Reason, An Introduction to Informal Fallacies* (2000 6 ed) by [York U. Prof. S. Morris Engel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S._Morris_Engel). Disclosure: I do not benefit or gain from, and am in no wise connected to, Avis.</sub>

> Present-day advertisements are 
>   subtle, but irrelevant appeals to sympathy persist, as in Avis Rent-a-Car's successful slogan: "We're number two."

[Avis's argument](http://www.slate.com/articles/business/rivalries/2013/08/hertz_vs_avis_advertising_wars_how_an_ad_firm_made_a_virtue_out_of_second.html) appears a Valid (but Unsound) Deduction to me. So how is it an Appeal to Pity?

Premise 1: If Avis is #2, then Avis will improve to be #1.
Premise 2: If Avis is #1, then you should choose Avis.
Conclusion. 3: You should choose Avis.

Comment: Alternatively: Avis, being #2, has more motivation to improve than #1, leading to better customer service and quality of product. I suspect there is a common belief these days that the company in the dominant position doesn't care as much about its customers as those vying for dominance.

Comment: Wrong interpretation. That was only part of the slogan. The main slogan was We try harder - we're #2. Had nothing to do with pity. Wrong interpretation. It meant that they tried harder for customer satisfaction. You can read about it here - http://www.projectrebrief.com/avis/#page=overview